# Iterating over PEB DllName shows only exe name

Tags: c, windows, winapi, shellcode

I'm trying to get a list of the loaded modules within my application (pertaining to security/shellcode so please refrain from WINAPI calls). I'm iterating over the PEB->Ldr doubly linked list of modules, but every time I print the DLL's name, it simply prints the name and path of the currently executing application.

In others' code, I've seen that they just case the current `LIST_ENTRY` pointer to be a `PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` and you can directly call `FullDllName` that way. However, to actually get the base address, for example, you need to call `Reserved2[0]` instead of `DllBase` which is understandable due to the fact that the `LIST_ENTRY` is 8 bytes into the struct, but it doesn't explain why you can call `FullDllName` directly.

[Here's an example.](https://github.com/zerosum0x0/LoadLibrary-GetProcAddress-Replacements/blob/master/load/main.c) Note the `return (HMODULE)pLdrDataTableEntry->Reserved2[0];`

I'm using Windows 10 x64 in x86 Release Mode with Visual Studio 2015.

```
void ListModules(void) {
    PPEB lpPeb = __readfsdword(0x30);
    PPEB_LDR_DATA lpLdr = lpPeb->Ldr;
    PLIST_ENTRY lpFirst, lpCurrent;
    lpFirst = lpCurrent = lpLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;

    do {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY lpDataTable = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpFirst, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        wprintf(L"%s ~ %d ~ 0x%08x\n", lpDataTable->FullDllName.Buffer, lpDataTable->DllBase, (DWORD)lpCurrent);
        lpCurrent= lpCurrent ->Flink;
    } while (lpCurrent && lpFirst != lpCurrent);    
}
```

The output I receive is just multiple references to the current application name:

```
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d53a18
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d53930
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d53da8
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d54078
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d54a68
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x00d54910
C:\Programs\Project\file.exe ~ 2818048 ~ 0x7743fbf4
```

This is very likely do to MSDN's infamous undocumentation, but how can I resolve this, preferably in a 'standard' way that wouldn't require defining my own structure, although I'm certainly not against it.

Am I not iterating correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at to this line

```
    PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY lpDataTable = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpFirst, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
```

but `lpFirst` you not changing in loop ! so and got the same records all time. you need change `lpFirst` to `lpCurrent`

also

```
while (lpCurrent && lpFirst != lpCurrent);
```

`lpCurrent` never become the NULL - this is circle list, so condition must be

`while (lpFirst != lpCurrent)`

also must be not

```
lpFirst = lpLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
```

but

```
lpFirst = &lpLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList;
```

of course access to this list must be synchronized (`LdrpLoaderLock` critical section) but, if you want anyway ..

**!! this is not recommended to use !! only for demo/test**

```
void ListModules() {
    PPEB lpPeb = (PPEB)((_TEB*)NtCurrentTeb())->ProcessEnvironmentBlock;
    PPEB_LDR_DATA lpLdr = lpPeb->Ldr;
    PLIST_ENTRY lpHead = &lpLdr->InMemoryOrderModuleList, lpCurrent = lpHead;

    while ((lpCurrent = lpCurrent ->Flink) != lpHead)
    {
        PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY lpDataTable = CONTAINING_RECORD(lpCurrent, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
        DbgPrint("%p %wZ\n", lpDataTable->DllBase, &lpDataTable->FullDllName);
    }
}
```

but even in shellcode better first got pointers to some api, and then use it. for example [`LdrEnumerateLoadedModules`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/d55/ldrapi_8c_source.html#l01111)

**this is not recommendation to use. demo only for OP**

```
void CALLBACK EnumModules(PLDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY mod, PVOID /*UserData*/, PBOOLEAN bStop )
{
    *bStop = FALSE;
    DbgPrint("%p %wZ\n", mod->DllBase, &mod->FullDllName);
}
    LdrEnumerateLoadedModules(0, EnumModules, 0);
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work based on this. I see that I accidentally used lpFirst instead of lpCurrent, but that wasn't the only issue. Thanks! And I know you said "this is not recommended to use," but is there a particular reason?

Comment: @Goodies - 1) access to this list must be synchronized (`LdrpLoaderLock` critical section) 2) `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` can be potential changed. really it all time changed in every new windows version, but by adding new fields only. the first fields - until stable. but in all case this is your choice - use or not.

Comment: I'll be testing it on multiple versions of windows.

Comment: @Goodies - now  code which I paste - correct worked on all windows versions (xp - win10 1607). but this is now. and if will be no problem with synchronization (nobody load/unload dll at time, when we enumerating)